# jQuery pick a random value from a array of strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random

I know how do this in PHP, but in javascript arrays are weird.

So I have a set of image transitions which have effects that use easing equations.
For certain effects I want to pick up a random value from a array of multiple values:

something like:

`easing: randomFrom(array('easeOutElastic', 'easeOutBounce', 'easeOutSince')),`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
function randomFrom(array) {
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

// in your code
easing: randomFrom(['easeOutElastic', 'easeOutBounce', 'easeOutSince']),
```

Comment: I was sooo close, but you forgot to return :-P

Comment: @Neal, oops, that's what happens when you do too much Ruby.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
function randomFrom(arr){
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    return arr[randomIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a demo I was trying to get a random easing string ;)

```
function getRandomEasing() {
   var easingArr = [];
   for(easing in $.easing){
      easingArr.push(easing);
   }
   var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * easingArr.length);
   return easingArr[rnd];
}

var randomEasing = getRandomEasing();
```

Fun demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/psWvy/

Comment: I don't understand why in the original solution, you need to create a new array every time?  Why not just directly return an element inside of `$.easing`?  http://jsfiddle.net/psWvy/2/

Answer (score 1):

I am a late comer to this question.  If you don't mind adding a method to `Array`, you can:

```
Array.prototype.pickARandomElement = function() { 
     return this[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length)]; 
}
```

test run:

```
> [10, 123, 777].pickARandomElement()
10

> [10, 123, 777].pickARandomElement()
777

> [10, 123, 777].pickARandomElement()
777

> [10, 123, 777].pickARandomElement()
123
```

The following is just for fun:

```
Array.prototype.pickARandomElement = function() { 
    return this.sort(function() { return Math.random() - 0.5; })[0]; 
}
```

it is like shuffling a deck of cards and returning the top card.  But its time complexity is `O(n log n)` so I wouldn't really use it, and it is just for fun.  The first solution here is a solution with `O(1)`.